# Rooted tree with huge depth - DFS Traversal algorithm performance

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures, tree, traversal

Today, I learnt 3 DFS(Depth First Search) traversals for rooted trees i.e.,
In-order, Pre-order & Post-order traversals.

For instance, If I consider Pre-order traversal,

```
typedef struct SiblingTreeNode {
    struct SiblingTreeNode *parent;
    void *item;
    struct SiblingTreeNode *firstChild;
    struct SiblingTreeNode *nextSibling;
} Node;

typedef struct LCRSTree {
    Node *root;
    int size;
} Tree;


void preOrderTraverse(Node * node) {
    visit(node);

    if (node->firstChild) {
        printf("\n|");
        preOrderTraverse(node->firstChild);
    }

    if (node->nextSibling) {
        printf("-->");
        preOrderTraverse(node->nextSibling);
    }
}

void preOrder(Tree *tree) {
    preOrderTraverse(tree->root);
}
```

---

then nodes are visited in below sequence,

### [image]

Practically working for NMS(Network management System) applications, We use rooted trees(`LCRS` representation) to maintain hierarchy of network elements(metrics), **where depth of leaf node is pretty huge.**

Asymptotically, space complexity of pre-order traversal is `O(d)`, where d is the depth of the lowest leaf.

On applying any of these 3 traversals, there is a great chance for an application to crash, due to stack over flow.

For example - If you consider visiting node sequence(above) call stack is maintained from root to leaf, when you visited 3rd node.

With the given `Tree` representation above, Without maintaining explicit data structures(like stack), How to optimize the traversal algorithm, on rooted trees?

*Note: On construction, `Tree` looks like [this](https://github.com/shamhub/Computing/blob/master/7_Tree/Rooted_tree_representation/Representation/siblingTreeNode.png)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a non-recursive solution for Pre-order traversal, that uses the stack data structure insdead of the call stack in recursive.
if memory is still an issue, you can design a stack to offload some of it to storage, and reload it when needed.

```
void iterativePreorder() {
    TreeNode top;
    if (root == null)
        return;

    Stack<SiblingTreeNode> st = new Stack<SiblingTreeNode>();
    st.push(root);

    while (!st.empty()) {
        top = st.pop();
        //do traversal effect
        if (top.right != null)
            st.push(top.right);
        if (top.left != null)
            st.push(top.left);
    }
}
```

Comment: Without explicit stack on heap, Do we have any traversal algo?

Comment: Most tree traversals are based on DFS and BFS algorethems.
DFS, is stack based and BFS is queue based."
I think it would be hard avoiding them, since there is aneed to keep a state of traversals. 
You can offload some of the stack to storage (HDD, SSD).

Comment: In-order, pre-order & post-order are DFS traversals of rooted tree. How do you perform BFS on rooted tree?

Comment: start from the root, ad both children to the queue.
While queue not empty, dequeue a node, add it's chidren to the queue and so on.
It passes all nodes in a tree, but level by level order.

Comment: hmm Let me try both DFS and BFS iteratively now